# Column editing (Alt+Left mouse click and drag) is not working on Notepad++ while in remote desktop

Tags: notepad++, remote-desktop

Using remote desktop (in a citrix env), I dialed into my desktop from my laptop and opened a file in the Notepad++. I am not able to use the column editing feature in that scenario, however it works very well if I use it directly on the desktop (sorry, I dont have enough reputation to post a screenshot.)

In the remote desktop scenario, when I press Alt+click and drag, if I am in windowed mode, the window will start moving. In case of fullscreen mode, nothing happens.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does the Alt-Shift + Cursor Shortcut work? You mark the block with a keyboard Cursor movement while holding Alt and Shift.

Comment: Nops...Just tried that. Even that also doesn't work. Keyboard movement when I tried wont move the cursor at all.

Comment: Then you can try to assign simpler shortcuts (only alt or ctrl) to the Block-Selection. You find them in Settings, Shortcut mapper, Scintilla commands. You need to find all the ...RECTEXTEND entries. For example SCI_LINEDOWNRECTEXTEND. But you should try with one change before changing all.

Comment: WWooowwww!!! That just worked!! I changed all the RECTEXTEND entries to include Ctrl also and it really worked. :) Thank a million Lars!!! :) /o\

And to those who follow this: The trick would be here is that you need to press Ctrl+Alt+Shift and arrow keys in the same order. If that is changed it wont work when you Remote Desktop to it. However it still works with alt alone when you physically work on the Desktop :-)

Comment: I put my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default shortcut for block selection is quite complex ctl+alt+cursor. If the remote desktop software blocks these shortcuts, you have always the possibility to change the shortcuts to simpler combinations.

You find them in Settings, Shortcut mapper, Scintilla commands. You need to find all the ...RECTEXTEND entries. For example SCI_LINEDOWNRECTEXTEND.

Comment: What do you like to say?